# Why do I keep getting 'None' as a response while webscraping in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

Im going through thenewboston python tutorial for a web crawler and im tryong tp follow his steps but have not been able to get what i want. I want to get all the quotes from this website https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/
however it keeps returning back "None"

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'quote'}):
            href = link.get('quote')
            print(href)
        page += 1


trade_spider(1)`
```

I tried a lot of things however cant really find a youtube tutorial on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug lies with the line

```
href = link.get('quote')
```

`link` is of type `Tag`. You are calling the `get` method on it, which, according to the [documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=Tag#attributes), returns the value of the corresponding attribute. However, when you print your `link` variable, you can see that it is a `div` and does not have the `quote` attribute. Instead, you can access its `span` subtag to extract the quotes:

```
span = link.find('span', {'class': 'text'})
quote = span.text
print(quote)
```